# Cant using my Xiaomi Mi A1 in android studio

Tags: android-studio, xiaomi

I have xiaomi Mi A1 and i developing in Android Studio and i want to run my app on my phone so i turned my Developer Options on and also the USB Debugging on, but i still cant find my phone on 'Connected Devices' list when i want to Run my app from android Studio.

What im missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click here](https://adbdriver.com/downloads/) for downloading adb drivers for your device. Install the application and attach your device to your machine and try.
This is because your adb drivers might not have been installed.